# Sidekiq with Rails 4 on Cloud9 Dev and Heroku Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sidekiq

I am just not understanding how this works and need help. What I have done...

I have installed the sidekiq gem, I have added to the application.rb file

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  # ...
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
end
```

I have created a Job(not sure if this was necessary as I am using ActionMailer only right now)

```
rails generate job Example
```

I have added #deliver_later to the actionmailer

```
if po_collection.empty? == false
      VendorSender.open_order_sender(user, vendor, po_collection).deliver_later
end
```

Am I missing anything here? How do I know it is working? Also, server log seems like it is working, but I am still waiting for emails to be sent.

```
2016-09-30T14:11:21.109402+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2016-09-30T14:11:21.109509+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [9da34b85-8695-4a0f-939f-c1614b141cb7] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Sidekiq(mailers) in 1205.49ms
2016-09-30T14:11:21.110374+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3 TID-otddzp9gg ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper JID-3d86866a3e1d54bb0486c63c INFO: done: 3.415 sec
2016-09-30T14:11:21.111969+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [e70249d4-81ff-4ca3-8e8a-d8534cd59370] 
2016-09-30T14:11:21.111970+00:00 app[worker.1]: Sent mail to private@private.com (939.1ms)
2016-09-30T14:11:21.112015+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [e70249d4-81ff-4ca3-8e8a-d8534cd59370] Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2016 07:11:20 -0700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

from the root of your rails project.  You will see the jobs being processed in that window if it is working.

Comment: check to see my server log. Looks like it is showing in my server log not bundle exec sidekiq and then showing in terminal

Comment: this actually led to me figuring it out